# How can I fix Exception Value: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: django, django-views

My problem in this line:

```
args.update(csrf(request))
```

My function in vews.py:

```
def Login(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        print(user, username, password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            args['login_error'] = "Пользователь не найден"
            return render(request, 'HiPage/Login.html', args)

    else:
        return render(request, 'HiPage/Login.html', args)
```

What is module here and why is it uncallable?
(I made imports of csrf)

```
  File "C:\Users\Dmitry\Desktop\Shop-master\HiPage\views.py", line 51, in Login
    args.update(csrf(request))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `args.update(csrf(request))`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it's necessary to provide the template with csrf. I tried do it without this string, but I got csrf error

Comment: but this is not the template... In the template, you indeed write `{{ csrf_input }}`, but that does not justify the `args.update(csrf(request))` call. In fact the `csrf` is already validated *before* the request is triggered. That is done by the middleware.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56794595/how-can-i-fix-exception-value-module-object-is-not-callable?noredirect=1#comment100144331_56794595), you have a wrong understanding on how CSRF is implemented in Django.

> it's necessary to provide the template with csrf. I tried do it without this string, but I got csrf error.

That is correct. But you do not need to add this to the context variables. If you use `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` as middleware , then the check of the CSRF token happens automatically.

What you need to do, is define the [**`{% csrf_token %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-csrf_token) in your template, like:

```
<form method="post" action="...">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

In the view, there is no need to generate, or to check the CSRF token.

In your view, you should check `request.method == 'POST'` instead of `if request.POST`, since a POST request can be made without data.

According to [**PEP-8**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) it is also advisable to write functions in lowercase with underscores.

Finally, if you make a [**`redirect(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect), it is better to use the name of the view. If you later change the path of that view, then the URL to which you redirect will change as well.

```
def login(request):
    args = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print(user, username, password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('name-of-view')
        else:
            args['login_error'] = "Пользователь не найден"
            return render(request, 'HiPage/Login.html', args)

    else:
        return render(request, 'HiPage/Login.html', args)
```